# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Tags: php, model, yii

when i need to update ,i receive this answer.  what i should do?

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{       
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $recruit = Recruit::model()->findByPk($_POST['pid']);
        $recruit->title = $_POST['title'];
        $test->save();
            $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$id));              
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($_POST['pid']),
        'id'=>$id,
        'pid'=>$_POST['pid'],
    ));
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to activate the Yii Log error reporting so you can know which code that raise the problem

Comment: @aslingga what are you talking about? He is clearly using a variable (`test`) that has no value.

Comment: @Örs I just suggest him to activate the Yii WebLog Error reporting so he/she can know which code that produce the error. So he can learn how to read the error before asking.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `$test` class instance created, and i think you must use `$recruit`

```
 $test->save();
 //to
 $recruit->save();
```